# Unable to read from stream in Mono.Cecil

Tags: c#, mono.cecil

I'm trying to load an assembly from a string-based stream in Cecil, however I keep getting `System.BadImageFormatException` and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

What I'm trying:

```
var data = File.ReadAllText("/path/to/dll");
using(Stream s = StreamFromString(data)) {
    var module = ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(s);
}
```

And `StreamFromString` is defined as:

```
return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s ?? ""));
```

I've also tried:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
writer.Write(s);
writer.Flush();
stream.Position = 0;
return stream;
```

Using latest Cecil, .NET 4.5 on Windows Server 2012. Any ideas? Thanks :)

Edit: `ModuleDefinition.ReadModule("/path/to/dll")` works fine so it's not a corrupt dll issue.

Comment: You're trying to read a binary file as if it were a text file. Don't do that. Just use a `FileStream`. Assemblies aren't strings.

Comment: What is it that you're actually trying to do? Why isn't `ModuleDefinition.ReadModule("/path/to/dll")` good enought for you? Or maybe `using (var s = File.OpenRead("/path/to/dll")) { var module = ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(s); }`?

Comment: @Luaan I need to figure out a way to store DLLs as strings in a database, and then later read and analyze them without trying to write to any file. Can't use a filestream.

Comment: @svick I need to analyze a bunch of DLLs stored in a database as strings in an environment that doesn't support direct reading or writing to files.

Comment: Why *strings*? Databases can usually handle binary blobs even easier than strings.

Comment: @Luaan the particular database I'm dealing with doesn't have binary blobs. It's an in-house proprietary system (like Hadoop, but on top of C#). I was trying to base64-encode the DLL data and storing it onto the system.

Comment: Well, if you want to use Base-64 encoding, use that. But UTF-8 is *not* base-64. If the database supports some ASCII-ish encoding, that might also be an option - something that has 1:1 byte to character mapping (unlike Unicode).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why it worked - but reading into a byte array using `File.ReadAllBytes` and writing to the `MemoryStream` directly without using the `StreamWriter` seems to have solved it.